# Как сделать сортировку картинок в лендинг странице

Tags: css3, html5

Подскажите как реализовать данный блок. По возможности посоветуйте где почитать или посмотреть как воплощаются данные блоки с картинками. И как называется эта реализация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это какие то скрипты галерей на яваскрипте , вот например  [Justified.js](http://nitinhayaran.github.io/Justified.js/demo/) и вот [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)